# Turn static website into a dynamic website

Tags: html

I just wanted to know how can i turn my static website into a dynamic website. I have created a static HTML website and want to turn it into a dynamic website. Can anyone tell me what steps should i take? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A dynamic website means to use server sided scripts for the creation of the websites which are controlled and processed by the server before being sent to the client. It will be simple so learn php or other server sided languages such as asp.net and get a server or hosting service or just install XAML or WAMP on your local machine so that an apache server environment is created. And then re-construct your pages with .php as its extension and then reconsruct the pages using php script. Learn Php its simple. Any more clarifications just comment

Comment: Replace `PHP` with the language of your choice.